# bash autocomplete feature doesn't work when I create function for emacs

Tags: command-line, bash, emacs, auto-completion

Details about my system: I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS on Oracle Virtual Box 4.3.6, from Windows 8.1 installed on an Asus Laptop. I'm using bash_completion version 1.3 release (I got this from the comments on the /etc/bash_completion file)

I thought bash always did auto complete for files and directories after a command. But after a google search and reading more about the bash_completion thing, I realized that this was different for different commands. But I'm facing a problem with this auto-completion feature of bash when using an alternate way to invoke `emacs -nw`.

I have defined `ee` as a function in my `~/.bash_aliases` file. I know this is not an alias, but I am just using a function to do what an alias would do:

```
function ee () {
    emacs -nw "$@"
}

export -f ee
```

I thought that I could still use `tab` completion with the ee function if I typed a partial file name. This just doesn't seem to work. 
Whereas if I typed in `emacs -nw` followed by a partial file name the tab completion works perfectly. I really don't understand what is missing here. 
I checked the output of the command `complete -p` and I get the following for both `emacs` and `ee`:

```
eakangk@eakan-u-vbox:~$ complete -p | grep 'ee'
complete -F _filedir_xspec ee
eakangk@eakan-u-vbox:~$ complete -p | grep 'emacs'
complete -F _filedir_xspec emacs
```

Wouldn't that mean both commands should give me the same sort of behaviour when attempting auto completion?
Edit: I hadn't seen the `ee` line in the `/etc/bash_completion` file when posting the question. But now I know it is there. 
But the /etc/bash_completion file has the following lines:

```
complete -f -X '!*.@(gif|jp?(e)g|miff|tif?(f)|pn[gm]|p[bgp]m|bmp|xpm|ico|xwd|tga|pcx)' ee
complete -f -X '*.@(o|so|so.!(conf)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class)' vi vim gvim rvim view rview rgvim rgview gview emacs xemacs sxemacs kate kwrite
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the [bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) package. It has some custom completion set for emacs, and apparently that same completion fails when the command name is different.

I don't use bash-completion myself, but I did a quick look at the source, and found this:

```
_install_xspec '*.@(o|so|so.!(conf|*/*)|a|[rs]pm|gif|jp?(e)g|mp3|mp?(e)g|avi|asf|ogg|class)' vi vim gvim rvim view rview rgvim rgview gview emacs xemacs sxemacs kate kwrite
```

which is probably used to say "for these commands, do not complete files ending with .gif, .mp3, .avi etc", and I'm guessing that if there's no _install_xspec line for your ee command, it doesn't complete anything.

Looking at the _install_xspec function, it simply puts these values in an associative array named `_xspecs` using command name as key, so if you run, `_xspecs[ee]=${_xspecs[emacs]}`, the ee command should get the same completions as emacs gets.

Comment: Wow! [geirha](http://askubuntu.com/users/9016/geirha) thanks for the tip. But I'm curious where you found that bit of code. I thought I had to just look at the custom completion overrides. And all the custom completion configuration should be in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`. But a `grep` on `/etc/bash_completion.d/` directory didn't help me find those lines. And the trick didn't work :'(.

Comment: @EakanGopalakrishnan, in `/etc/bash_completion`

Comment: @saurav of course I would if it solved my problem. But it did not. I'm still trying out alternatives.

Comment: @EakanGopalakrishnan, I had a quick look again, and I noticed I had typoed the arrayname. It's `_xspecs`, not `_xspec`. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: is it working for you? I just can't get it working. I'm going crazy.

Comment: @EakanGopalakrishnan, I just tried it in a VM, and it did indeed cause ee to yield the same completions as emacs.

Comment: You too on VM?? great! okay. So I think I am a little closer to the solution, but not there yet. `complete -r ee` did the trick. In my `/etc/bash_completion` file there was this line: `complete -f -X '!*.@(gif|jp?(e)g|miff|tif?(f)|pn[gm]|p[bgp]m|bmp|xpm|ico|xwd|tga|pcx)' ee` and I also read the answer to [superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/142211/bash-completion-processing-gone-bad-how-to-debug) and the trick worked. what version of bash_completion are you using? I couldn't find that function in the bash_completion file. I am now learning more about `complete`.

Comment: @EakanGopalakrishnan, yes, as I said, I don't use bash-completion myself, and I don't want to install it again on my main system just to test. Anyway, `complete -r ee` is also a good solution. It removes the custom completion for the ee command which will result in the default completions instead, which is good enough for most commands.

Comment: cheers! we just wrote the same thing :) edit your answer with that and I'll accept it as my solution. thanks a lot for playing with the problem. nailed it :)

Comment: @EakanGopalakrishnan, my answer was based on the latest version available at the bash-completion site. The version in Ubuntu is likely a bit older. the `complete -f -X ...` line there does not match what you claimed `complete -p` output... perhaps you've been mixing versions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12678/discussion-between-eakan-gopalakrishnan-and-geirha)

Comment: just noticed that I hadn't accepted your answer. Even though it didn't completely solve my problem. it was the closest. thank you very much for your help @geirha